# Sudo Path - not finding Node.js

Tags: unix, ubuntu, node.js, path

I need to run node on my Ubuntu machine with sudo access. The directory of node is in the sudo path but when trying to run it i get a command not found. I can explicitly call node which does work.

```
//works
node
>

which node
/root/local/node/bin/node

echo sudo $PATH
sudo /root/local/node/bin:/usr/bin/node:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

sudo node --version
sudo: node: command not found

//explicitly calling it works
sudo node /root/local/node/bin
>
```

Comment: Your last command is executing a program called "bin" in /root/local/node. If this works, your first `which` there is lying.

Comment: @Wooble actually explicit call should go to /root/local/node/bin/node so far i can guess from different versions of node installation. beck's last command is incomplete.
PATH is added manually and it missed /node at it's end. /node/bin is always directory when building from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, I don't think there's such a thing as a "sudo path" - your second command there is just echoing "sudo" followed by your regular path. In any case, if you're running things with `sudo` you really, really should **not** depend on a path - you should give the explicit pathname for every command and file argument whenever possible, to minimize security risks. If `sudo` doesn't want to run something, you need to use `visudo` to add it to `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Would the person who downvoted care to enlighten me as to what I got wrong?